# AWS Sage Maker doesn't show Job Definitions

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Out of nowhere, Sage Maker stopped showing Notebook Job Definitions.

Access is correct, I cleaned the browser, and there are jobs running from those job definitions, but Sage Maker is not showing the list - what I can do?